# How to implement email verification through OTP in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, one-time-password

In my rails app, im implenting mobile verification, through OTP. (Using active_model_otp).
now my customer requirement is he want the Email verification also through OTP(means an email with 6 digit otp needs to send to the email. if he enters it, the email verification should happen.)

currently the email verification is happening, through a confirmation link, that is getting sent to the user at the time of user registration(Devise default email verification functionaly)

now my question is how can implement the OTP verification in this context, can i use the same gem to accomplish it ? when i checked the gem document i did not found any info related to email verification using otp though this gem(active_model_otp)

do i need to change these gems (devise, active_model_otp) to implement it or we need to implement it manually.

Comment: Hi John...did you find any helpful links?

Comment: no @Manoj please help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

He John, i am doing the same, yet not finished it dough, so can't share the code right now. Essentially, my idea is to make additional /mfa/otp_qr and /mfa/otp_mail controllers (and views) and a parent view for users to select either mail or qr authentication, ie in /users/registrations/edit.html.erb (and route it after, accordingly).
Active_model_otp gem just handles sec.codes generation/comparision, not how to display those to user (ie with QR code) or send it via email (i guess SMS is also doable).